# Is there a point to collecting Achievements?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

After playing for a few hours, I have collected a handful of Achievements (out of 749) in *Xenoblade Chronicles X*.

I was wondering if there were any in-game rewards for collecting some or all of them. Something like getting to meet Yoshi after collecting all Power Stars in *Super Mario 64*, or receiving the Fierce Deity Mask for collecting every other Mask in *The Legend of Zelda: Majora's Mask*.

Are there such rewards, or are Achievements only for personal recognition, like in most Xbox or PlayStation games?

Comment: It's just a personal thing.

Comment: In the last game they gave you extra gold and experience for each one you earned, but I haven't noticed that in this game yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completing an achievement awards Credits and/or experience. There don't seem to be any other in-game effects. Of course there is the personal aspect of simply having completed them as well.

From the [wiki page](http://xenoblade.wikia.com/wiki/Achievements_(X)):

> Achievements are earned by meeting certain requirements. **Upon completion, the player is awarded with a certain amount of Credits and/or Experience Points**. There are a total of 749 achievements.